# KnockoutJS css and class in the same binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Despite the section in https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html i wasnt able to use css and class together, instead I could use two different css bindings: http://jsfiddle.net/g9sot5qb/

Am I doing something wrong or is the documentation inaccurate?

```
<span class="cls1 cls2" data-bind="text: title,css: {active: active}, class: myClass" ></span>
<span class="cls1 cls2" data-bind="text: title,css: {active: active}, css: myClass" ></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` binding is a Knockout version `3.5` feature.

From the v 3.5 [release notes](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.5.0-beta):

> The new class binding supports dynamic class strings.
>   This allows you to use the css and class bindings together to support both methods of setting CSS classes.

---

Your jsfiddle is using an older version.

Also note that the `observable active` must have a `true` value in order to get the `css class` `'active'` applied.

See the (runnable) example below, where both a `class` and `css` binding are active.

```js
var viewModel= {
  myClass: ko.observable('test'),
  title: ko.observable('Title'),
  active: ko.observable(true)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.test{
  color: red
}

.active {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span class="cls1 cls2" data-bind="text: title, css: {active: active}, class: myClass" ></span>
```